# Font Awesome in CSS pseudo elements not showing

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have the font-awesome free version css linked in my html/php index, so if I call any FA icons on that page directly they work fine.

However, I'm trying to apply some to pseudo elements in my css and I can't get it to work. It only shows an empty square/box.

I've looked at the docs and I've tried this with single and double quotes, but no matter what it's an empty square still.

Is it clear to anyone what I'm doing wrong here?

```
a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
content: "\f106";
font-weight: 400;
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
content: "\f106";
}
```

VERY Minimal codepen, most CSS and JS stripped out
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEeZWX

Comment: Can you isolate the problem in a codepen or similar env?

Comment: have you trie, brand or free for the font, not sure solid is avalaible ... `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands","Font Awesome 5 Free";`

Comment: @CameronHurd didn't think about that, just added very stripped down version of one

Comment: @G-Cyr Yes I currently have them all being used in the CSS but still nothing

Comment: okay, may it has to do with the font-size ;)   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zarbYj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Font family should specify `Free`.
Also note that for solid icons you would have to use `font-weight:900`

```css
a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f106";
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
  content: "\f106";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i> Pages
      </a>
    </li>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm accepting this because it explained the issue at hand, however, I also had to set pseudo elements to true with JS

Comment: This only seems to work if you're loading via the Web Fonts & CSS method (`link` tag) as opposed to the SVG & JS framework (`script` tag).

Comment: @Todd Yes, because only the Web fonts & CSS method uses FONT. SVG and JS is rendered using SVG files, not a FONT.

Comment: solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Use "Free" in `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";`** 
I use also `display: inline-block;` to set them side by side
Hre is working JSFiddle to your code:https://jsfiddle.net/8vge3rkv/

```css
a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
content: "\f106";
font-weight: 900;
display: inline-block;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
content: "\f106";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#" aria-expanded="false">try me</a>
```